# SQL Query VBA Excel

Tags: sql, query, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

Boa tarde!

Tenho um problema com uma consulta no Access via formulário.

O Formulário é do vba do Excel, que se conecta ao banco de dados.

Segue abaixo o código completo.

Esse é o código do botão. Ao clicar ele valida qual dos dois botões está marcado (valor true). Se nenhum dos dois estiver selecionado ele mostra mensagem de erro.

Se opção de BP está marcada, ele chama a função e passa para ela o numero do BP digitado pelo usuário no input box. O mesmo acontece caso seja selecionado o CPF.

```
Private Sub btn_consulta_Click()

    Dim BP      As String
    Dim cpf     As String

    BP = controlectform.nmbpbox.Value
    cpf = controlectform.nmcpfbox.Value

    If controlectform.optbp.Value = True Then

        Call SelectNome("controle", "NOME", "BP")

        Exit Sub

    ElseIf controlectform.optcpf.Value = True Then

        Call SelectNome("controle", "NOME", "cpf")

        Exit Sub

    Else

        MsgBox "Selecione a opção de consulta!", vbCritical

    End If

End Sub
```

A função recebe os parâmetros e monta a query de pesquisa no banco de dados através da variável sql. É nela que está o where. Mas ele não funciona.

```
    Function SelectNome(Tabela As String, Campo As String, Criterios As String) As Variant
    Dim NOMEDB As Variant

    Dim sql As String
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="_
& enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

cn.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

**sql = "SELECT " & Tabela & "." & Campo & " From " & Tabela & " where " & Criterios & ";"**

```
rs.Open sql, cn

If Not rs.EOF Then
Do While Not rs.EOF
NOMEDB = rs(0)
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If

cn.Close

controlectform.nomecolaboradorbox.Value = NOMEDB

End Function
```

Ou seja, eu chamo a function:

Call SelectNome()

E passo os argumentos seguindo a ordem, Tabela, Campo, Critério. Nesse caso:

Call SelectNome("controle", "NOME", "BP")

O meu critério é o Where BP.

Comment: Do jeito que está escrito, seu `While` vai percorrer todos os registros da sua consulta e só quando chegar ao final da tabela (`EOF`) o `loop` será encerrado e depois o valor de NOMEDB copiado para o controle. O problema está no `where` que não está funcionando? É isto?

Comment: Exatamente. Os dados estão todos formatados como texto. Mas o where não funciona de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Então poste seu `where` para o entendermos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça, consegui efetuar a consulta.

Segue abaixo o código desenvolvido

```
Function SelectNome()

    Dim NOMEDB As Variant

    Dim sql As String
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="_
& enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

    cn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    sql = "SELECT controle.NOME FROM controle WHERE BP = '"_ 
& controlectform.nmbpbox.Value & "';"

    rs.Open sql, cn

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            NOMEDB = rs(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    cn.Close

    controlectform.nomecolaboradorbox.Value = NOMEDB

End Function
```

Como podem ver a única alteração que fiz foi montar eu mesmo a query sql, ao invés de passar os parâmetros pela chamada da função.

Agora a consulta funciona certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Ismael,

Segue abaixo o código completo.

Esse é o código do botão. Ao clicar ele valida qual dos dois botões está marcado (valor true). Se nenhum dos dois estiver selecionado ele mostra mensagem de erro.

Se o botão de BP está marcado, ele chama a função e passa para ela o numero do BP digitado pelo usuário no input box. O mesmo acontece caso seja selecionado o CPF.

```
Private Sub btn_consulta_Click()

    Dim BP      As String
    Dim cpf     As String

    BP = controlectform.nmbpbox.Value
    cpf = controlectform.nmcpfbox.Value

    If controlectform.optbp.Value = True Then

        Call SelectNome("controle", "NOME", "BP")

        Exit Sub

    ElseIf controlectform.optcpf.Value = True Then

        Call SelectNome("controle", "NOME", "cpf")

        Exit Sub

    Else

        MsgBox "Selecione a opção de consulta!", vbCritical

    End If

End Sub
```

A função recebe os parâmetros e monta a query de pesquisa no banco de dados através da variável sql. É nela que está o where. Mas ele não funciona.

```
    Function SelectNome(Tabela As String, Campo As String, Criterios As String) As Variant
    Dim NOMEDB As Variant

    Dim sql As String
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="_
& enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

cn.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

***sql = "SELECT " & Tabela & "." & Campo & " From " & Tabela & " where " & Criterios & ";"***

```
rs.Open sql, cn

If Not rs.EOF Then
Do While Not rs.EOF
NOMEDB = rs(0)
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If

cn.Close

controlectform.nomecolaboradorbox.Value = NOMEDB

End Function
```

Ou seja, eu chamo a function:

Call SelectNome()

E passo os argumentos seguindo a ordem, Tabela, Campo, Critério. Nesse caso:

Call SelectNome("controle", "NOME", "BP")

O meu critério é o Where BP.

Comment: Olá, Sugiro que edite sua pergunta colocando todos os códigos e conteúdos dentro da pergunta para fins de registro.

Comment: Isso mesmo Humberto, edite sua pergunta com os dados que colocou aqui nesta parte, já que ela é destinada apenas para a resposta. Quando a sua questão, você passou o valor "BP" (entre aspas) para o parâmetro Critério, mas, neste caso, não está sendo passado o valor da variável, e sim, o texto "BP".

Comment: Coloquei as informações no campo de pergunta conforme orientação. E fiz a seguinte alteração no código:  Coloquei "ByVal" no critério, ficando assim:  Function SelectNome(Tabela As String, Campo As String, ByVal Criterios As String)  Mas agora o código dá erro. Aparece uma mensagem de erro em tempo de execução: No value given for one or more required parameters. Sei que é simples de resolver, mas tenho um conhecimento muito básico de vba e ainda estou engatinhando na sintaxe correta.